# Worst SQL Ever?

Tags: sql, database

What is the worst SQL query you've ever seen?  What made it bad?

Comment: Might want to make this a community WIKI else someone will shut it down.

Comment: He certainly has enough rep to make his own question a wiki.  Wikify this.

Comment: Highlighting what constitutes poor programming practice IS about programming (and more so than some other wishy-0washy topics I've seen)

Comment: @mitch: It's not a question with an even remotely definitive answer.  Instead it's a question that expects a lot of valid responses.  Ergo: wiki.

Comment: I just found the worst post ever.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table
```

Seen right after I typed and executed it, I had forgotten the WHERE clause.  Now I always run a SELECT statement first and change the SELECT to DELETE after I am satisfied that the proper rows will be affected.

Comment: Ouch..! I'm paranoid, I always surround update/delete statements with begin tran/rollback, try it and then execute the inner part when I feel safe.

Comment: I do something similar, except I just write TableName as TableNameFOO while I am authoring it.  I also keep the "To:" field of e-mails empty before I write the entire e-mail and proofread... just in case ;)

Comment: @ocdecio: This was MySQL, before they supported transactions :(

Comment: @sean: I have a colleague that starts DELETE statements with WHERE 1=0 just in case they forget to add the correct WHERE clause before they hit the execute button.  Also, I do the same thing with emails.

Comment: ditto, and i am amazed how often, i get a different result set than expected.

Comment: Guys... select * into z_backup from <important table> as your first step. Then go hog wild.

Comment: I've done this before whilst at work, fortunately I was working on the development server and I just restored the last working database backup.  I also wrote a web page for managing educational status for employees recently and left out the where clause.  Let's just say everyone has a degree now.

Comment: haha.  I always start with BEGIN on production.

Comment: And this is why I believe that DELETEs and INSERTs should require the programmer to express his intent explicitly to apply the statement to all of the rows, e.g. DELETE ALL FROM table

Comment: Ouch.  I felt that pain myself.  Once.

Comment: Happened to me once with the same result - I always select first now and then change the query when satisfied with the results.

Comment: Same things goes for UPDATE, especially on table containing (linguistic) translations :)

Answer (score 27):

The classic [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/) of course:

```
WHERE name = ROBERT'); DROP TABLE students;--
```

Comment: Why did you get negative votes for this? It is hilarious!

Comment: Oh, someone removed their negative vote.

Comment: We call him Little Bobby Tables

Comment: How is this considered "worst"? It is brilliant.

Comment: The greatness is not the query, it's the name :)

Answer (score 13):

Worst *USE* of an SQL query every:

A SELECT query that that counts the number of lines corresponding to a certain condition, called in the stopping condition of a for loop.
Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < query("SELECT COUNT .... WHERE ..."); i++)
{

}
```

And no, the result of the query doesn't change every iteration. Yes I realize the server is going to cache the result.

Answer (score 10):

A PL/SQL (Oracle) stored proc that sorted a result set using a [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It was discovered when I and the DBA were asked to figure out a severe performance problem. The developer, an Oracle "expert," had worked on it for over a week. He explained with a straight face that he learned about Bubble Sort in his computer science class. The algorithm is commonly used to illustrate poor performance.

Replaced the whole mess with an ORDER BY clause. Performance improved by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: There may be some Oracle consultants who aren't unbearably bad but I've never met one. I worked with one group whose Oracle "expert" had written an entire accounting program using "Bat" files tied to keys. Thus, "I.bat" ran an Invoice form, "R.bat" ran reports. Yes, this was in the late 90s.

Answer (score 9):

A customer was storing a comma delimited list of 3 values in a varchar field (classic ASP application) so they had a stored procedure that looked something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    Field LIKE @Param + ',%'
    OR
    Field LIKE '%,' + @Param + ',%'
    OR
    Field LIKE '%,' + @Param
```

It should be obvious why it's horrible :)

Comment: ouch! That makes my teeth hurt!

Comment: I have seen similar things in a large production program :S

Comment: Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Don't know if better is the right word but -- WHERE ',' + Field + ',' LIKE '%,' + @Param + ',%' -- will probably run faster. Of course you shouldn't have comma delimited data inside fields in a RDBMS.

Answer (score 7):

My own, which is far to long to post here -- closing now on 3500 lines

I have to really share the blame with an absolutely horrible schema. What started off as a simple exercise in pivoting denormalized data using some unions turned into an unwieldy nightmare.  It's badly in need of repair.

Runner up is this:

```
select 
case datepart(mm,getdate())
when 1 then 'Jan'
when 2 then 'Feb'
when 3 then 'March'
when 4 then 'Apr'
when 5 then 'May'
when 6 then 'Jun'
when 7 then 'July'
when 8 then 'Aug'
when 9 then 'Sept'
when 10 then 'Otc'
when 11 then 'Nov'
when 11 then 'Dec'
end
```

There are no typos in that post -- that's how it was written.  Thank you, consulting dollars!

I of course refactored with Select left(datename(mm, getdate()), 3)

Comment: 11 mapped both to Nov and Dec??  Really?

Comment: We discovered this gem in December.

Comment: In a workplace that will remain nameless, your fix would actually be frowned upon because it breaks the spelling for "Sept" and "March" (never-mind that it fixes a bug).

Comment: @Shivasubramanian: Yes - there was a spelling error in Otc; that is one of the points.

Comment: @TrickyNixon: the advantage of that solution is that it is not affected by locale - so even the French, Spanish, German or Japanese users get forced to use the English abbreviations for the month names.  :D

Comment: <sarcasm>Doesn't everyone speak American English? Bah!</sarcasm>

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: This is also a disadvantage. It is quite possible that there is a language out there where two months share the same first 3 letters.

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from users where clue > 0;
0 results found.
```

Comment: the worst thing about this sql is that it never returns any results, no matter where you run it

Comment: This is why we should be able to upvote comments :)

Comment: What happens why you run this query on the Stack Overflow database? Does it still return 0 results?  Or does it just return user ID 22656

Comment: Why is this bad SQL?  Why play shoot-the-messenger?

Answer (score 5):

When I first got my current job my first project was to create an application that summarized our license usage data in our computer labs.  He insisted that he didn't want the backend database to be normalized because joins were "too expensive."  It being my first week, I wasn't in a position to argue.

Now, in order to extract any useful data from the database, one has to "undo" the denormalization in every query that needs to extract summaries to remove the duplicated data in each row.  Of course, these are the only queries that are actually used.  You see a lot of nested selects that would be completely unnecessary if the data were normalized, such as:

```
select location, sum(login_time) as total_login_time
from
    (select location, session_id, max(login_time) as login_time
     from sessions
     where location in ('lab1','lab2') 
           and session_start >= @start_date 
           and session_end <= @end_date
     group by location, session_id) tbl
group by location
```

Although, the query itself isn't particularly ugly -- though some are -- the process of having to jump through hoops every time to undo the unnecessary denormalization hurts.

Now the boss is gone, but I don't have time to rewrite it...

Comment: make some views to denormalise the data for you :D

Comment: This is just wrong on so many levels.  Especially the comment about joins being "too expensive."

Answer (score 4):

In a posting to the [comp.databases.informix](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.informix/browse_thread/thread/56ec41fed00c94fe/9e4ed5335e7ce8d9?lnk=gst&q=%22create+table%22+author%3Aleffler#9e4ed5335e7ce8d9) news group - a genuine working Informix table (which I do not recommend using):

```
CREATE TABLE VIEW
(
    DECIMAL     CHAR(30),
    NOT         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SERIAL      DATE NOT NULL,
    NULL        CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    INTEGER     DECIMAL(13,6) NOT NULL
);
```

It helps (marginally) if you know that SERIAL is a type in Informix databases - basically,  one of the types for generating automatically allocated numbers serially.

Answer (score 3):

```
SUBSTRING(
(SUBSTRING(LastName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', LastName)) + ', ' + FirstName),
0,
CHARINDEX(' ', (SUBSTRING(LastName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', LastName)) + ', ' + 
FirstName), LEN(LastName) + 3)
)
```

They apparently weren't familiar with RTRIM;

```
RTRIM(LastName) + ', ' + RTRIM(FirstName)
```

Answer (score 2):

select * from *

Real bad.

Comment: SELECT * FROM * WHERE * = '%%'; i dont dare to check if this actually works.

Comment: or any cross join between two or more reasonably big tables.

Comment: cross joining between two large but narrow tables is often an optimal solution for matching sets for example - many-to-many is a common problem

Answer (score 2):

**It's probably not the worst but I see this far too often ([Misuse of the group by clause](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/12/14/8546.aspx)):**

```
SELECT
  C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, C.CustomerType, C.Address1, C.City,   
  C.State, SUM(S.Sales) as TotalSales
FROM
  Customers C
INNER JOIN Sales S
  ON C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
GROUP BY
  C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, C.CustomerType, C.Address1, C.City, C.State
```

**Instead of:**

```
SELECT
  C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName,
  C.CustomerType, C.Address1, C.City,
  C.State, S.TotalSales
FROM
  Customers C
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(Sales) as TotalSales FROM Sales GROUP BY CustomerID) S
ON
  C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
```

Comment: call me out on this is you will but I disagree that as a rule that 1 is bad and 2 is good.  With a more complex example, 2 becomes quite a bit harder to maintain. To me, 1 is very clear in its intent and therefor, simpler to maintain.  2 can offer better performance but the gain may not be worth it.

Comment: Also, rule 2 is slower under mysql. mysql--.  the latter is even more maintainable if you disassemble it and use string-substitution to compose the final query.  INNER JOIN ( $customerTotals )  :D

Comment: Will there not be an extra join with syntax 2? May or may not matter

Comment: +1 for the interesting refactoring - good point.  Version 1 is a simple pre-SQL-92 query adapted to use the SQL-92 join notation.  The second shouldn't be slower - it does the grouping on a single table and then joins that with the original (unless, I suppose, the optimizer doesn't order the sub-query result and exploit that order in merge join with the customer table, in which case it might be slower than an indexed join).

Answer (score 2):

read it out loud.

```
select [select],*,star as [as] from [from],[order] order by [by]
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be something like http://slashdot.org

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the worst (especially followed by a painful and null rollback):

```
DROP DATABASE;
ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've seen a (greater than) 4000 line TSQL stored procedure that was a chain of IF statments for matching parts of addresses. It could be reduced to less than 50 lines!

I'm saving the code for a future DailyWTF!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

What made it so bad was the code was relying on getting the results in order based on a timestamp. This had apparently worked for a while before I got called in to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In an Access Database, there was a query like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bad_2 INNER JOIN Bad_1 ON Bad_2.Bad_1_id = Bad_1.ID;
```

and both tables had a field with the same name.  When Access comes across a field name for a second time, it makes up a new name for it.  The previous guy used the generated field name in code.

Answer (score 1):

Seen many woeful pieces of SQL in my time.
One that comes to mind is of the form

load data from a file, loop over that file, accessing db for each line in file.

Seems ok on test systems with 10 or so lines, 100K-1million = nasty even for primary
key lookups.

BTW, the solution is to load the data into the db and think in sets.

-- Choose your favourite lang eg. perl, python ...

load file into data structure (eg array)

`for (1 .. n) loop

 myid := array[n];

 select * from table where id = myid;

 if the row exists update table set ... where id = myid;

end loop;`

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM some_table WHERE some_thing IN (SELECT some_column_from_wrong_table FROM correct_table WHERE some_id=something).

The some_column_from_wrong_table has a column that wasn't even in the table, but it was in another table.
Problem was the correct_table was named 'Event' and somehow it returned ALL rows instead of NO rows (or more importantly, an error!).

Two lessons learned: NEVER EVER, under any circumstances, name a table after *any* form of system name. Second thing was run select statements first, then change to delete.

This was SqlServer 2005 by the way. I'm still pissed it didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the one [reposted recently](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Classic-WTF-Now-Thats-A-Neat-Trick.aspx) on the dailywtf, the story that comes with it is wonderful as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id IN (".implode(",",corrected_cats($ad->id)).") ORDER BY name ASC
```

Yes, you're reading that right... comma separated fields in a field.